# reactjs passing a callback results in undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm tring to build an exam generator using React v0.13.3. The problem is when i click `Add a choice`, the callback function I passed as a prop to the Question element is undefined. Here is the full snippet.

By the way, i've pasted the transformed script and should you want the jsx script. here it is [not-yet-transformed.js](https://gist.github.com/migzisreallywewwhat/d1b9c7da7302557e5ca0)

http://jsfiddle.net/acqwg429/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because in your Exam component's map function inside render method *this* keyword is not refering to the Exam component object. you can either fix issue with Es6 arrow function or create local variable called *_this* and  assign *this* to *_this* before map function

with arrow function

```
    var questions = this.state.questions.map((question, index) =>{
        return (
            React.createElement(Question, {
                key: index, 
                index: index, 
                src: question, 
                handleAddChoice: this.onAddChoice})
        );
    });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jkwhrs1j/

With local variable assignment
jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gzevgjfb/

Answer (score 1):

Following pashaplus' answer, you could also pass the context argument to the map function like this:

```
var questions = this.state.questions.map(function (question, index) {
    return (
        <Question 
            key={index} 
            index={index} 
            src={question} 
            handleAddChoice={this.onAddChoice} />
    );
}, this);
```